# Regarding the instance variables and method variable binding

Tags: java, instance-variables

I am learning Java and as per knowledge I know that all objects are created at runtime when the function is called.

I came across these two examples which have let me to a confusion

Example 1:

```
class Animal {

    void jump() {
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

    void jump(int a) {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {

    void jump() {
        System.out.println("Rabbit");
    }
}

public class Circus {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();
        cat.jump();
        rabbit.jump();
    }
}
```

Output of this Code is:

> Animal
>   Rabbit

Example 2

```
class Employee {

    String name = "Employee";

    void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

class Programmer extends Employee {

    String name = "Programmer";

    void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public class Office1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Employee programmer = new Programmer();
        System.out.println(emp.name);
        System.out.println(programmer.name);
        emp.printName();
        programmer.printName();
    }
}
```

O/P of this example is

> Employee
>   Employee
>   Employee
>   Programmer

Now my question is why in example 1 `cat.jump()` is returning output as 'Animal' 
and in example 2 why `programmer.printName()` is returning 'Programmer'.

I think this has something to do with dynamic and static binding but I'm not able to understand how it is being implemented in these examples.

Comment: I'm going to reformat this, do you mind?

Comment: It's because of `(int a)` on `jump` in `Cat`.  This makes it an entirely different `jump` method.  For more information, you'll want to read some tutorials, such as the trail that starts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: @AnubianNoob Sure please.... anything that can help me understand this concept

Comment: Next time, you should try to fix formatting and grammar errors yourself. This question was pretty good and shows effor, but badly asked. Next time, your question might not make up for its lack of clarity Just a friendly reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to think about this by copy/pasting inherited methods in your head.

The `Cat` class will look like this:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    void jump() { System.out.println("Animal"); } // <-- Inherited from Animal
    void jump(int a) { System.out.println("Cat"); }
}
```

So when you call `cat.jump()`, the compiler sees that there is a no-args `jump()` method and binds `Animal#jump()` there.

`Rabbit` looks like this:

```
class Rabbit extends Animal {
    void jump() { System.out.println("Rabbit"); } // Overrides jump() from Animal
}
```

So for `rabbit.jump()` the compiler binds the only `jump()` available and dynamic polymorphism ensures that the `Rabbit` version is called.

---

Now, fields are *not* polymorphic, and are bound at compile time (if memory serves). Because the compiler works off the *reference* type of objects, the field bound will depend on the type of the *reference*, and not the type of the object.

Therefore, `programmer.name` actually refers to the `name` field of `Employee`, because the reference type of `programmer` is `Employee`. Because both `employee` and `programmer` have reference types of `Employee`, `Employee` will be printed.

As a side note, the `name` field in `Programmer` is *hiding* the `name` field that was inherited from `Employee`. Inside the `Programmer` class (for `this` references), the `Programmer` version of `name` will be used, but outside of `Programmer` the `name` field used will depend on the reference type you are using.

Methods *are* polymorphic, so the method that runs depends on the *dynamic* type of the object. Therefore, `employee` will call `Employee#printName()` and `programmer` will call `Programmer#printName()`, as those are the runtime types of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first scenario, you have called jump() on a Cat object which inherits this method from its base class Animal.

I think you were expecting "Cat" to be output but this is not the case as you called jump(), not jump(int).

Answer (score 0):

**General information:**

Java is Dynamic binding or late binding, this means that at runtime, the program will see if the method called is overridden by checking the dynamic type of the object and will call it. In other world, having:

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
cat.jump();
```

JVM at runtime, before calling jump() will look at the dynamic type of `cat` and it will notice that it is of dynamic type Cat. Therefore it will search in Cat if there exist an overriden method called jump(). If it finds it, it will use it, otherwise it will go up to the parent (Animal) and execute `jump()` from there.

Please note that static methods behave differently and are not overidden.

**Back to your code behavior**

In example 1, you are calling `jump()` and not `jump(int n)`. In class Cat, you are **overloading** the method jump() and not **overridding** it. So if you try to call cat.jump(1); you will have as output `Cat`. Overloading a method will create an additional method with same method name but different different argument.

Putting all together

You are confusing 2 concepts, **dynamic binding** and **Overloading vs Overriding**.
Java is dynamic binding, it will execute the method closest to the real type (dynamic type) of the object created. If a method was overriden by a child having this example: cat.jump() where cat has static type (Animal) and dynamic type (Cat), will execute the method jump() from the dynamic type Cat if found there, if not found it will execute it from the static type Animal.

**Overriding** a method is creating a method that already exist in a parent class inside a  child class. (Here dynamic binding play it roles)

**Overloading** a method is creating a method that already exist in a parent class inside a child class but with different arguments. (This is why you are not getting Cat as output)

Comment: Hmmm, I learned that virtual calls in Java don't incur any performance penalty through searching as you seem to be implying. At least the decompiled bytecode seems to be calling `Animal#jump()` immediately...

Comment: Unlike c++ JAVA looks at the closest meaning of the object and will execute the closest method to the object. Scientifically speaking, it will look at the dynamic type Cat and check if jump() is there, if not call the parent method.

Comment: Yeah, I know how dynamic dispatch works. I'm just thought dynamic dispatch was implemented using a virtual method table or something instead of actively searching for the implementation at runtime, so deep inheritance hierarchies wouldn't incur a performance penalty.

Comment: @user3580294 Late binding affect the performance of the application because as you said it needs to search in the virtual table for the correct method to execute. I believe this is one of many things that makes Java slower than C++

Comment: But when *everything* is virtual (as in Java [until the JIT compiler gets to that method]), deep inheritance hierarchies won't matter. I do agree that virtual methods in general would affect performance though. So I don't really have anything to complain about except the way you said virtual methods are resolved.